# Looking for a Clojure/LISP equivalent to Scons

Tags: makefile, clojure, scons, leiningen

I have found a [Scons](https://www.scons.org/), a Python-based build language similar to Make.  However, I can not seem to find a Clojure/LISP equivalent to this type of build language tool (despite LISPs being seeming well-suited for this job).  Does such a tool exist, and where is it located?

**Background:** I am considering using Clojure/Leningen as a potential candidate to replace Make as my build language for a C++ project I am working on.  Is this a worthwhile effort?  Is Clojure and/or LISP really a useful build language for a C++ project?

Comment: I like `make`.  I *despise* Scons.  They serve related roles, but I don't think they are at all similar.  And this matters because there is a big difference between "I'm looking for a build-management tool", and "I'm looking for a tool like `make`" or "for a tool like Scons".

Comment: You can use Scheme in make files. It's not Clojure, I know, but... Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will find anything as concise as Make in the Clojure world since Make is tailored to its purpose.

However, the next closest thing is probably Babashka. Here's [an example](https://book.babashka.org/#_dependencies_between_tasks) of how to work with task dependencies and modification times:

```clj
{:tasks {:requires ([babashka.fs :as fs])
         :init (do (def target-dir  "target")
                   (def jar-file "target/foo.jar"))
         -target {:task (fs/create-dirs target-dir)}
         jar {:depends [-target]
              :task (when (seq (fs/modified-since jar-file
                                             (fs/glob "src" "**.clj")))
                      (spit jar-file "test")
                      (println "made jar!"))}
         uberjar {:depends [jar]
                  :task (println "creating uberjar!")}}}
```